# Why do my rest endpoints not work on my node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

My index.js file looks like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express();
var currentVideo = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Q-ovNuireY';

// parse application/json
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(res) {
  console.log("sup");
});

app.get('/currentVideo', function(req, res) {
  res.send(200, {youtubeSrc: currentVideo});
});

http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT ||3000, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

My static page in public loads up and my server starts up fine and prints out the Example app log.  When I try to hit my get endpoint though it doesn't work.  I've been hitting http://localhost:{port}/currentVideo and I get a 404.

Comment: `http://localhost:{port}/currentVideo` was `{port}` properly replaced? What HTTP client did you test with?

Comment: Yea the port is dynamic, but its right.  And I just tested it in the browser.

Comment: @Grammin please post here your javascript call from public page to your API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and tested it locally using curl. The request worked fine.

Could you share your public page? Any log is noticed in Chrome Developer Tools Console when you try to load data?

```
curl -v http://localhost:3000/currentVideo
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /currentVideo HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 58
< ETag: W/"3a-FMsS5hMXa1tcIFnGeYHinQ"
< Date: Sun, 18 Sep 2016 20:34:04 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"youtubeSrc":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Q-ovNuireY"}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is much more of a comment than an actual answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at StackOverflow and I'm just trying to help.

Comment: The browser logs look fine, they endpoints just give me a 404.  My html file is loaded like: http://localhost:63342/last/app/public/index.html.  In my package.json I have something like:   "main": "app/index.js", I don't know if that matters or not thought?

Comment: Don't worry. Just delete this answer and post a comment to the question above (you can include that console log in a pastebin and link it, for example).